# How much does it cost to run the Tor network if we divide it per Tor user?

Tags: network-health

How much does it cost to run the Tor network if we divide it per average Tor daily user? Tor has like what 1.7 million daily users, so like is it 1$ per month per Tor user? Has anyone done any such estimate?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, someone already tried to do the calculation:

> To sum up, that would make the entire Tor network run for approximately $90,000 a month or $1,072,860 a year. Roughly the price for a (very) small tier 3 datacenter!
>
> Considering there are 1.6 million users using Tor, that would make the average user cost under a dollar per year — which is pretty cheap for some of its use cases and the associated benefits (censorship circumvention, privacy, …).
>
> https://blog.0day.rocks/how-much-does-the-tor-network-cost-to-run-9d4ea4780a57

In sum, that would make the Tor network cost 5.59 cents per month per Tor user.